# android connective receiver

Tags: android

I'm getting the error like

```
(java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.lmx.example.ConnectivityReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

from the following code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String strconnectiondata = "action: " + intent.getAction();
        Log.d(ConnectivityReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), strconnectiondata);
        SessionManager sess = new SessionManager(context);
        if (sess.isLoggedIn()) {
            TelephonyManager myTelManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            myTelManager.listen(new DheuttoPhoneStateListener(context),
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            Log.i("CALL STATE","Phnone State:"+PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }else {
            Log.i("LOGIN INFO:", "Still didn't login for accept the call");
        }

    }
```

Here I'm checking whether user is logged in or not. If logged in my application, then I have to check all the incoming calls. When I get the incoming call, the phone number should be stored, and after it ends the active call and will go to the related mobile number transaction page. In the transaction page I have an option to log out of the current mobile number transaction. Until log out other incoming calls are not allowed.

My Log is:

```
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.lmx.example.ConnectivityReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.lmx.example.SessionManager.<init>(SessionManager.java:28)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.lmx.example.examplePhoneStateListener.<init>(examplePhoneStateListener.java:18)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.lmx.example.ConnectivityReceiver.onReceive(ConnectivityReceiver.java:20)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
02-23 11:00:26.413: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  ... 10 more
02-23 11:00:27.316: D/dalvikvm(474): GC_CONCURRENT freed 321K, 51% free 2881K/5831K, external 731K/1038K, paused 12ms+74ms
```

Comment: Can you include logcat log

Comment: i have included my logcat and updated

Comment: The exception is happening in the constructor of the SessionManager. You should include that code as well. But even better, try to analyze the stack trace: the error is in line 28 of SessionManager.java. I guess you haven't initialized something or similar.

Comment: I have created empty constructor and corrected errors in SessionManager.But i have errors in ConnectivityReceiver(java.lang.NullPointerException).